# CEF browser showing old content on the window

Tags: wpf, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I was creating a browser window for my WPF application. During the visibility change I am loading the URL, but when I change the URL content and load the same URL it is showing previous content first, then after a blinking it shows the updated data.

```
        void OnWindowVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsBrowserInitialized) return;
            if (window.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
            {
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    LoadNewUrl();
                    window.Activate();
                }));
            }
            else
            {
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    ChromeBrowser.LoadHtml("<html><body><h1></h1></body></html>");
                }));
            }
        }
```

Suppose the URL contains "ABCD" as data. First time it is showing the correct content. After the update the data becomes "ABCDEF". Now on `Load()` the initial content is showing then the updated content.

Is there anything else I need to do for avoiding this issue?

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: I don't get the issue. You show the browser window, then load a new content, right?

Comment: @amaitland The version is **r104.4.24+gdf482f6+chromium-104.0.5112.102**. Mostly reproducible in slower machines. I used cpukiller3 to slow down my dev machine to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @273K Showing window, there I am loading the content with URL. During the next load it shows old content first then some blinking then the actual content. Sometimes the window is blank only.

Comment: Please show more code, it's still unclear what the issue is. Loading a new content is an asynchronous action. If you show a browser window at the `Load` call, you will see the old content first for sure.

Comment: @273K Updated the content. Please see that snippet. Here I am doing an empty html loading when the visibility is hidden or collapsed so that I can see the blank window instead of last data before the actual URL load happens. But seems like this is also causing the same issue.

Comment: See my answer, it's too long for a comment, but can be an actual answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what `LoadHtml()` does, it's not a part of the native CEF API. In any case the blank page is about:blank, i.e. `ChromeBrowser.Load("about:blank")`.

Are you aware of stopping all activities in the hidden browser? It seems to be the issue - you load an empty page and hide the window, the browser stops any activities, then you activate the window and still see an old content, then an empty page causes "blinking", and finally a new content is shown.

You should catch change visibility request, cancel it, load about:blank and hide the window on load completion. The client handler has appropriate events.

Comment: This is a nice information. Can I ask one thing - What is difference if I am loading the URL when the window is not visible and when the window is visible can it show the content since the Chrome Browser already got the address. 

After using this "about:blank", intermittently that old data issue is happening. The last address before any new visibility is "about:blank" only, then how can it show the old data.

Comment: Whether the cache is holding the valid old data rather than about:blank

Comment: You completely misunderstood what I was explaining. You should not expect an immediate clear window after `Load("about:blank")`. It's asynchronous operation and needs some time after `Load` for performing many actions in other processes and threads. If you hide the window immediately before or after `Load`, you pause the browser. When you unhide the window, it continues actions from the point of the interruption, thus you see the old content, because actions were not complete yet.

Comment: Is there any way to do a background loading of the URL without making the browser window visible?